# What is the largest volume box that can be shipped?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

To send a box, a courier service requires that the length plus twice the width plus the
double the height does not exceed 280 centimeters. What is the largest volume box that can be shipped

I know that volume of a box is $(x)(y)(z)$ and I know that $2x+2y<=280cm$ and I think its using Lagrange multiplier but I don't know how to exactly use that is <=280 I used to use just "="

Comment: The inequality is $x+2y+2z\le 280$. And yes, use $=$

Comment: Then I should Use x+2y+2z=280 as restriction?

Comment: Yes you should.

Comment: @KevinDuran If $x+2y+2z < 280$ then you can always add a tiny bit more to any one, or all of $x,y,z$ to make it equal to $280$, also making a bigger volume box

Answer (score 0):

$V = x y z = (280 - 2 y - 2 z) y z$. But clearly (by symmetry) the solution occurs when $y = z$.  To see this:  there is nothing in the problem that distinguishes the depth $z$ and the width $y$.  We could relabel $y$ with $z$ and the problem would be identical... as is clear from the functional form:  $(280 - 2 y - 2 z) y z$.  Given that there is a single optimum, that demands that $y = z$ at that optimum.

Thus $V = (280 - 4y) y^2$.  Set $\frac{dV}{dy}= 2 (280 - 4 y) y - 4 y^2 = 0$ to find $y = z = 140/3$, and resubstitute to find $x = 280/3$.  Then $V = 5488000/27$.

Comment: This "clearly" is not so clear.